# Getting total subscription list for a particualr user

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription, in-app-subscription

I have added In-App purchase in my android application. Added subscription for month and a year.

Is there any way to get the list for particular application user who have subscribed item, cancel item etc.

I want to get the subscription history for particular application user.

Is there any In-APP API available to do so ?

What might be any other way ?

Comment: see `Purchased Items List` in https://medium.com/@KarthikPonnam/inapp-purchase-subscription-android-8fff52fa4d3b

Comment: I am using IabHelper class. Not BillingClient,

Comment: @Priyankagb I am using IabHelper class. Not BillingClient,

Comment: you can get a list from `IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener` by calling `inventory.getAllPurchases()` method

Answer (score 1):

You should use Play Billing Library (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview). This is the best practice announced by Google Play. Since 2021, this shall be the only way to integrate with Google Play Billing.

Now to your questions, you can use:
1) getPurchases(Type.Subs) to get the active subscription of the current user.
2) getPurchasesHistory to get the most recent purchase history for all of your in-app items for the current user.

Comment: So, you are saying that instead of using IabHelper, we should use BillingClient (Billing Library) ?

Answer (score 0):

After all, To get all the purchase details, 
I have done as below inside : `onQueryInventoryFinished()` method :

```
 List<Purchase> aList=inventory.getAllPurchases();
 Log.e("***** size",""+aList.size());
 for(int i=0;i< aList.size();i++)
  {
     Log.e("***** title",""+aList.get(i));
  }
```

So, As it's response am getting app the purchases and canceled subscription.